# C# How do i create a tabcontrol with non-closable tab

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

How to create TabControl with non closable tab. I have windows.FormApplication and i am trying to create "Simple WebBrowser with Tabs", so i can add and close tabs, but i want to create nonclosable the latest tab.

Comment: Well, how are you closing them now?

Comment: I think `non closable` is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add the following condition.

```
if (tabControl1 != null && tabControl1.TabPages.Count > 1)
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
```

That would allow you to close any tab up to the last one.

Comment: It's not an answer on question, because question is completely incorrect. @Leo, probably, referring to some example project for beginners called "Simple WebBrowser with Tabs". You have no idea, how tab closing implemented in demo project, so your answer is useless.

P.S. Much better to re-formulate question or just remove it.